# iOS: Handling subview with another controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, xib

I've got `MainViewController` with xib where I created two `subviews` and connected them with `IBOutlets` in the `MainViewController`. I need it to be that way, because the `MainViewController` handles resizing of the `subviews` by the user.

Now I want to create two ViewControllers with xibs for the subviews, so that I can fill the subviews with content without thinking about what the MainViewController does with them.

How to do it?

I started with creating two `SubviewControllers`, initiazlized in the `MainViewController` overridden initializer. But I do not know how to connect the `SubviewControllers` with `subviews`, especially that both `subviews` occur in more than one xib - in the main xib they are empty, and in "their" xib the have the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use UIView of a viewController(`MainViewController`) in another viewController(`NextViewController`) you have to add your MainViewController as a child of `NextViewController` in `NextViewController` something like this..

```
MainViewController * child = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:child.subView1];
[self addChildViewController:child];
[child release];//for NON ARC
```

Comment: I did so and the subview view shows up, but I can't see it in the main xib.

Comment: what do you mean by " I can't see it in the main xib".

Comment: As I said in my question, I want to have more than one xib. One is main (owned by MainViewController), where I add constraints to subviews, and in the other (owned by SubViewController) I want to add content of the subview. After I followed you instructions I don't see the subview in main xib, so I can't add contraints in the Interface Builder.

Comment: in interface builder it can not disappear. check that if this subView was deleted by mistake or not?

Comment: It is in the subview's xib. In the main xib it didn't disappear, but it never was there. I expected it to appear after I added it.

Comment: when you are adding a view via code, it will never affect interface builder. Interface builder or xib can not be changed through coding. When you are writing code to change properties of a control(UIView, UIButton etc.) the property changes remains till application is running, but xib will not reflect those property changes.

Comment: Hope you will understand this.